# Delphi assign image from ImageIndex though code

Tags: delphi

I am using a devexpress button with an imagelist that contains several images.
I am trying to change the image when the button is clicked.

Here is the code that does not work but appears valid.

```
if UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex = 3 then
UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex := 4;
if UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex = 4 then
UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex := 3;
```

To me, this should be valid.

Comment: You do realize that if the `ImageIndex` is 3 initially then you end up setting it back to 3, don't you? Maybe the 2nd `if` should be an `else if` instead?

Comment: With the help of logic the code can be shortened to `UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex := 7 - UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex;`

Comment: @AmigoJack And after two years your colleague has to debug your code..... Don't do this.

Comment: `case UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex of 3: UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex := 4; 4: UpdateBTN.OptionsImage.ImageIndex := 3; end;`

Comment: @JanDoggen What's the point? Being unable to understand [subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction)? Wait until code is written by AI and who'll then be able to understand it for debugging purposes...

Comment: Maybe `3` and `4` should be named constants?